A Question about the Matrix Representaition of an Operator
I'm reading an argument which assumes that $H$ is a Hilbert space and $A\in B(H)$.I'm having difficulty understanding one matrix representaion of $A$.
First, the author decomposes $H$ as $H=\overline{R(A^*)}\oplus null(A)=\overline{R(A)}\oplus null(A^*)$ (so there seem to be two different decompositions of $H$?), and then claims that $A=\begin{pmatrix}A_1&0 \\\ 0&0\end{pmatrix}$, where $A_1$ is a function $A_1: \overline{R(A^*)}\rightarrow\overline{R(A)}$ that has the following two properties: a) $A_1$ is injective; b) $A_1$ has dense range.
I have no idea what is going on here. First, why are there two decompositions of $H$? I think we only need one decompostion of $H$ in order to write out the matrix repersention for $A$ (with respect to that decomposition). Second, why does $A$ satisfy those two properties?

It’s not really clear to me what the author is trying to do here, so it might be better for you to provide additional details from this argument.

If I had to guess, though, I would assume this matrix decomposition is not written so that rows and columns use the same decomposition of $H$. Rather, it uses the first decomposition for columns and the second for rows. It’s better to think of $A$ as an operator from $H_1$ to $H_2$ with $H_1 = H_2 = H$ and the first decomposition pertains to $H_1$ while the second pertains to $H_2$, which might make it clearer. Then $A_1 = A|_{\overline{R(A^\ast)}}$. It is injective because $\overline{R(A^\ast)} = \text{ker}(A)^\perp$ and its range is $R(A)$, which is of course dense in $\overline{R(A)}$.
